# iOS Orientation changes across multiple views

Tags: ios

I am writing a iOS Tab Bar Application using iOS 5.1 SDK with storyboards for my UI design. My requirement is that whenever the app rotates to landscape mode, I need to show a calendar. I have figured out the calendar part, but what I am not sure about is how to implement the solution in such a way that it applies to the entire app.
Basically, what I am trying to avoid is handling orientation change on per view basis. Regardless of which view I am in, if I rotate to landscape orientation, I need to show this calendar view and of course get back to my original view when I switch back to portait mode.

Any clues or thoughts from anyone would be useful..

Answer (score 0):

You need to `subclass` your calendar view in all `viewcontrollers` and add a `subview` of your current view when your orientation goes to landscape..

you can also make your calendar class as a `singleton` to access anywhere in your project with same instance.